# Gitblit - daily statistics

Tags: git, statistics

Is there a plugin/tool/etc to Gitblit server that would do the following:

- create commits statistics per day, repo and user
- send created statistics on email?

The problem I want to solve is have some automated monitoring system for some of my projects.

I know that writing a "simple" script in bash/PowerShell is one solution, but maybe there is something already created?